# Music player that utilizes ReplayGain tags and can scrobble to Last.fm?

Tags: music-player

Is there a media player that can read [ReplayGain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_Gain) tags from the music files and adjust play volume accordingly? Also it will be appreciated if it can live [scrobble](http://www.last.fm/help/faq?category=Scrobbling) playing tracks to a chosen Last.fm profile.

As a bonus: Can it display currently playing song to a bluetooth handsfree with screen, like [SE MW600](http://www.sonyericsson.com/cws/products/accessories/overview/mw600)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I finally have decided to "normalize" all my music, specially for the car radio. The good thing is that you can revert ReplayGain changes easily losslessly.

Comment: Normalization is not the same as what ReplayGain does as the latter is way better.

Answer (score 2):

[Winamp](http://www.winamp.com/android) supports ReplayGain in its desktop versions, so the Android version might also support it (I'm not positive, but it seems reasonable). It definitely does support scrobbling, though I've not used it myself. You could give that a try and see if it fits your needs.

Answer (score -1):

[DeaDBeeF](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.deadbeef.android) supports replaygain and many file formats. Also has a nice interface, but its integration with the standard music library is not as good. Still, well worth a try.